# Postman giving a 500 internal server error with empty message when sending a post request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, postman

I am trying to build an app which will have help users put menus. But after sending a post request to add the menu in Postman, it gives a blank message with 500 internal server error. The request I am sending also fulfills the model but for some reason I still get the error.
[image]

The controller code-

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import Menu from "../model/Menu";
import User from "../model/User";

export const getMenu=async(req,res,next)=>{
    let menus;
    try{
        menus=await Menu.find().populate('user');
    }catch(err){
        return console.log(err)
    }
    if(!menus){
        return res.status(404).json({message:"no menu found"});

    }
    return res.status(200).json({menus})

}

export const addMenu=async(req,res,next)=>{
    const {title,price,image,category,user}=req.body;
    let existingUser;
    try{
        existingUser=await User.findById(user);
    }catch(err){
        return console.log(err)
    }
    if(!existingUser){
        return res.status(400).json({message:"Unabel to find user by this id"})
    }
    const menu= new Menu({
        title,
        price,
        image,
        category,
        user,
    });
    try{
       const session=await mongoose.startSession();
       session.startTransaction();
       await menu.save({session});
       existingUser.menus.push(menu);
       await existingUser.save({session})
       await session.commitTransaction();
    }catch(err){
        return res.status(500).json({message:err})
    }
    return res.status(200).json({menu})
};
```

The model code-

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const Schema=mongoose.Schema;

const menuSchema=new Schema({
    title:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    price:{
        type:Number,
        required:true,
    },
    image:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    category:[{type:String,ref:"Category",required:true}],
    user:{
        type:mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:"User",
        required:true,
    },
});

export default mongoose.model("Menu",menuSchema);
```

Comment: inside the catch block add `return res.status(500).send(err.stack)` it wiil say what is the actual error.

Answer (score 1):

It's returning 500 because you are returning a 500 in the catch block. Log the error and it will tell you why the error is happening.